# Up to date (lts-13.0) minimal base docker image for haskell/stack?

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack

I'm would like to deploy my haskell application on docker and the base image fco/stack-build that I've found takes 9GB ! Do you know a base image more minimal than that ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stack-build` is as large as it is, because it contains the required system dependencies of *all* packages on Stackage.

I am using the following base image for building and deploying:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

# Build dependencies
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes curl
RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes libtinfo-dev

# Without this haddock crashes for modules containing
# non-ASCII characters.
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

It's not really minimal if you just want to use the image during runtime as you wouldn't need stack in that case.

Comment: it's minimal enough for me :-) can't we control the version of stack installed ? I'm going to try "stack upgrade --binary-version 1.9.3" ....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that image might only be necessary to **build** the excutable, once you have it built you could use a multistage docker build or just copy the executable directly to a more slim image.

---

The dockerfile is available here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/etc/dockerfiles/stack-build/lts-13.0/Dockerfile

You could remove these commands (which probably add up to the bulk of the size):

```
# Use Stackage's debian-bootstrap.sh script to install system libraries and
# tools required to build any Stackage package.
#

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/stackage/$BOOTSTRAP_COMMIT/debian-bootstrap.sh | bash && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```